# Keybind to correct a suggestion in Rider

Tags: c#, rider

I'm new to Rider and in Visual Studio I can press Alt+Enter to correct something to what Visual Studio suggests.

I've tried to illustrate the situation in the picture below. So the editor (ReSharper (?)) suggests I use the wording MyRoom instead (which makes sense for methods), but is there a command to auto correct this as with visual studio 2017? And in that case, what is its name? I've been trying to find it in the keymap but cant find it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's apparently called "Show Intention Action" and was bound to something weird on MacOS! I've bound it to cmd+enter now. Thank you for your help though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but there is an extension call `IntelliSpell`

Easy-to-use, one-click operation to spell-check your Microsoft Visual Studio files, projects, or entire solution.

you can find it here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GrapeCityinc.IntelliSpell-SpellCheckerforVisualStudio

Answer (score 0):

In the Rider [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html#detect) it is written, that you can also use `Alt + Enter`. You could also try `Ctrl + .`. If I remember correctly it worked in Visual Studio with Resharper.